# SQL: How to make a replace on the field ''

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a very but tricky question for you guys. So, listen I have a field with spaces and numbers in one of my table columns. The key part is transform the content in a decimal field. The drawback is basically that for some rows I could get something like:

```
    ' 1584.00 '
    ' 156546'
    '545.00 '
    '    '
```

So, to clean up my column, I have done a LTRIM and RTRIM so spaces gone. So now for a couple of records where the record were just spaces the new content is **''**. Finally I need to convert this result to a decimal.

**Issue:** The thing is that for field that contend just the spaces the new result is **''** and I'm not able to apply a REPLACE on this because it's a blank and the code below doesn't work:

```
SELECT REPLACE('','','0')

-- Final current verison
SELECT CAST(COALESCE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Gross_Weight],' ','0'),',',''),'0') AS DECIMAL(13,3))
```

How could I figure it out?

thanks so much

Comment: Are you trying to update a column with blank value to zero?. Please provide more details.

Comment: @Shammascheck out the update buddy

Comment: Could you check the select statement with case in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(MyColumn, ''), 0)
```

This has the side-effect that you will also turn NULL values into 0, which you might not want. If that's a problem then a simple `CASE` statement should do the trick:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MyColumn = '' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(MyColumn AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) END
```

Obviously you'll also have to incorporate any other manipulations that you're already doing.

Answer (score 1):

No need for replace, just concatenate a zero to your column, like

```
SELECT RTRIM('0' + LTRIM(column))
```

Comment: But it seems he already changed the data. I am not sure though.

Comment: Then he can still do `'0' + column` before converting to decimal

Answer (score 0):

I presume your data is in a table.
Lets call this table 'DATA' and the column 'VALUE'
Then you might use the below query

```
UPDATE DATA SET VALUE = 0 where VALUE = ''
```

To select the value do the below

```
select case  ltrim(rtrim([Gross_Weight])) when ''
   THEN 0
   ELSE ltrim(rtrim([Gross_Weight])) END
```

Let me know if i get the requirement wrong.